# Json object with numeric member is not binding to Object.IntegerProperty in MVC controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

Using JQuery 1.9, I'm calling the following ajax statement:

```
var data =
{ 
    PropertyId: 1912,
    Position: 0,
    Description: "State sales tax",
    Rate: 5,
    RateIsPercent: true
};

$.ajax(
{
    type : "PUT",
    url: "/api/taxes/5",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});
```

In Chrome or Firefox, I see that the request body (the stringified data) is valid JSON.  It looks like this:

[image]

I've verified with other parsers, all of which confirm that this is valid JSON.

**The problem is that the PropertyId member in this JSON object does not bind to the object property in the MVC controller method, even though all the other members do.  I get an error of:**

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "newTax.PropertyId": [
      "The field PropertyId must be between 1 and 2147483647."
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see in the above image, the PropertyId value is 1912.  That is obviously an acceptable int32 value.

**So why is it throwing this validation error?**

Here's the object I'm wanting it to be bound to:

```
public class Tax : CloneableObject
{
    public Tax() { }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    [Display(Name = "Property ID")]
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Min(0)]
    public int Position { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(256)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Rate Is Percent")]
    public bool RateIsPercent { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the action method in the controller:

```
// PUT: api/taxes/5
public Tax Put(int id, [FromBody]Tax newTax)
{
    return TaxBusiness.Update(id, newTax).ExecuteOrThrow();
}
```

Here are the routes that are configured:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "ApiPutPatchDelete", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: null, constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE") });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "ApiPost", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}", defaults: null, constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "ApiGet", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") });
```

I don't believe there's a problem with it hitting the right route because it works if I pass name/value post data instead of json.  For instance, if I call this instead:

```
 curl -X PUT http://app/api/taxes/5 -d "propertyId=1912&rate=50&etc..."
```

It works perfectly fine.

The PropertyId is the only member that isn't getting bound correctly.  There are no other validation errors other than this one.

**What I've tried...**

If I remove the `[Range(1, int.MaxValue)]` attribute, I don't get any validation errors but tax.PropertyId ends up with a value of `0`.

If I remove *all* attributes from PropertyId, the value comes through perfectly fine as `1912`.

Again, none of this happens if I use a name/value post string to send values like:

```
 "propertyId=1912&rate=23&etc...."
```

All validation works as intended if I do that.  This is only happening when I post a json string.

**Update:**

It appears to be related to the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute.  If I remove that, everything works.  If I leave that, the problems occur.

Is `[IgnoreDataMember]` skipping over json object members when deserializing?  I thought `[IgnoreDataMember]` was only used when serializing, not deserializing.

If so, is there a different way of telling serialization to ignore the PropertyId field while making sure it gets included during deserializing?

Comment: I added [a SO question for the IgnoreDataMember part of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16087979/ignoredatamember-attribute-is-skipping-json-object-properties-during-deseria) since this appears to be a specific issue having to do with IgnoreDataMember.

Comment: Why not use two different models, one for serialization and one for deserialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read, there is no way to use an attribute to only stop serialization and not deserialization.  `IgnoreDataMember` and `JsonIgnore` both do the same thing.

The way I got it to work was to remove the attribute completely and change over to the `ShouldSerialize` method which is conditional serialization.

[Json.NET doc on ShouldSerialize](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConditionalProperties.htm)

Answer (score 0):

In property PropertyId

```
[Required]
[Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
[IgnoreDataMember]
[Display(Name = "Property ID")]
public int PropertyId { get; set; }
```

I think problem is attribute [IgnoreDataMember]. You try using attr [JsonIgnore] instead of [IgnoreDataMember]. See code below:

```
[Required]
[Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
[JsonIgnore]
[Display(Name = "Property ID")]
public int PropertyId { get; set; }
```

Don't forget add reference Newtonsoft.Json and

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

in your code.

Hope usefull!

Comment: IgnoreDataMember and JsonIgnore basically do the same thing.  They both stop serialization and deserialization.  I ended up taking off the attribute and using the `ShouldSerialize` method of [conditional serialization](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConditionalProperties.htm).