# IgnoreDataMember attribute is skipping json object properties during **DE**serialization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, validation, attributes, asp.net-web-api

[According to the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute.aspx), the IgnoreDataMember attribute is only supposed to be considered during serialization.

From what I'm seeing, however, MVC model binding is using it during **de**serialization of json as well.

Consider the following class:

```
public class Tax
{
    public Tax() { }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
}
```

If POST/PUT the following json string to an action method:

```
{"Position":0,"Description":"State sales tax","Rate":5,"RateIsPercent":true,"PropertyId":1912}
```

I get the following validation error:

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "newTax.PropertyId": [
      "The field PropertyId must be between 1 and 2147483647."
    ]
  }
}
```

Both the `[Range(1, int.MaxValue)]` and `[Required]` attributes are invalid.

If I remove the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute, everything works fine.

Is there a different attribute that can be used which will tell MVC binding not to ignore the property during deserialization?

This only happens when posting a json string.  If I post a name/value string, everthing works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer has to do with the behavior of Json.net.  That's what the model binding is using and it's checking `IgnoreDataMember` for both serialization and deserialization making it useless for me (since I want to only use it for serialization).

The `JsonIgnore` attribute works exactly the same way.

Given that, I pulled all the ignore attributes off my properties and switched to using json.net's conditional serialization methods.

So basically add this for the above PropertyId field:

```
public bool ShouldSerializePropertyId() { return false; }
```

That allows deserialization to come in but blocks serialization from going out.